# A lock could not be obtained within the time requested

Tags: java, database, locking, derby

I want to delete all data from tables or complete tables. For all tables, deletion was successful except for one. I get the same error if I delete a table or everything from a table.
Error is: **A lock could not be obtained within the time requested**

I use a Derby database and all delete functions are called from the same class / function

Delete function:

```
String TABLE_NAME = "brother_reports";
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), null);
            if (tables.next()) {
                String query = "TRUNCATE TABLE brother_reports";
                stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                stmt.close();
                conn.commit();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error DeleteBrotherReportsTable " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

Create table function:

```
String TABLE_NAME = "brother_reports";
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), null);
            if (tables.next()) {
                System.out.println("Tabela " + TABLE_NAME + " već postoji");
            } else {
                String query = "CREATE TABLE brother_reports( "
                        + "Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, "
                        + "device_id INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "location VARCHAR(255), "
                        + "pageCounter BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "drumNumber BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "avgCoverageAll FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "avgCoverageCurrent FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "avgCoverageLast FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "drumLTCounter BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "drumLTPercentage FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "staplerLTCounter BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "staplerLTPercentage FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "laserLTCounter BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "laserLTPercentage FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "kompMP BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "kompMPPercentage FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "komp1 BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "komp1Percentage FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "toner FLOAT NOT NULL, "
                        + "A4Counter BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "scanCounter BIGINT NOT NULL, "
                        + "drumReplace INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "staplerReplace INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "laserReplace INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "kompMPuvlak INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "kompUvlak INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "tonerReplace INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "mjesec INT NOT NULL, "
                        + "godina INT NOT NULL,"
                        + "status INT NOT NULL,"
                        + "PRIMARY KEY (Id))";
                stmt.execute(query);
                stmt.close();


            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error setupServicesTable " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

How to fix that?

Comment: What happens if you do `conn.commit();` immediately before you call `stmt.executeUpdate` for the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement? Does that help?

Comment: Also, are you using the same connection for the `CREATE TABLE` operation? If so, did you try doing a `conn.commit();` immediately after the `CREATE TABLE`?